# A-FRAME + mobile phone) how touch move up or down by finger gesture

Tags: aframe

my product is below (Please see by mobile phone)

https://pano-mixer360.com/viewer/sphere/11/43

in the case of move to left or right,
touch moving by finger gesture is working well.

but,
in the case of move to up or down,
touch moving by finger gesture is not working! It's problem.

what should I do?

using

```
A-Frame0.5.0
Safari iOS 10
```

my code

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 0 0">
    <a-entity>
      <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls>
      <a-entity id="myCursor" cursor="fuse:true maxDistance:30; timeout:500;" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring" material="color: #00ff00; shader: flat; opacity:0.5">
        <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="none" from="0.3 0.3 0.3" to="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
  <a-sky src="test.jpeg" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

by the way,
I tried clone look-controls.js

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js

and line #L173 replace to

```
x: radToDeg(hmdEuler.x) + radToDeg(yawObject.rotation.x),
```

as using yawObject.

but It's now working.
because touch moving listener(#L301-L313) is no set rotaion.x!

perhaps, 
I should calculation the rotation.x

```
yawObject.rotation.x = ????
```

but I don't understand how to calculation.

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

The problem is about `pitchObject` not `yawObject`,place the code into `onTouchMove` function in your clone of look-controls.js

```
var deltaX = 2 * Math.PI * (evt.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / canvas.clientHeight;
this.pitchObject.rotation.x -= deltaX * 0.5;
```

[image: this image can help you understand]